# Intellij IDEA Code Style - Insert blank line or additional indent after multiple condition

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style

When `if` condition is huge and take several lines then condition and body become a monoblock, because default indent is 4 and IDEA align multiline `if` to 4.

```
if (status != HttpStatus.OK.value()
    || doc.title().equals("Foo")
    || list.isEmpty()) {
    logger.info("Awful readability.");
    foobar();
    ex.execute(this);
}
```

OR

```
if (status != HttpStatus.OK.value() ||
    doc.title().equals("Foo") ||
    list.isEmpty()) {
    logger.info("The most horrible readability.");
    foobar();
    ex.execute(this);
}
```

Readability become so-so. For this I want insert a blank line after condition or insert additional indent for conditions by autoformat.

```
if (status != HttpStatus.OK.value()
        || doc.title().equals("Foo")
        || list.isEmpty()) {
    logger.info("Good readability.");
    foobar();
    ex.execute(this);
}

OR

if (status != HttpStatus.OK.value()
    || doc.title().equals("Foo")
    || list.isEmpty()) {

    logger.info("Good readability.");
    foobar();
    ex.execute(this);
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't find something in Code Style options.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA code formatting does not have any support for automatically inserting blank lines in method bodies.

Comment: Additional indent support?